# No errors, infinite loading: where should I search?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, logging, ubuntu-16.04, postgresql-9.5

Here is the context, it just happened today:

- Ubuntu 16.04, PostgreSQL 9.5
- Infinite load when querying any page which uses PostgreSQL  (with no message)
- Infinite load when running any query with `psql` (with no message)
- Nothing in particular in `/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.5-main.log`
- Nothing in particular in `/var/log/syslog`
- Server load was OK (~1% for each processor, memory almost not used, disk space OK)

Then, everything worked fine just after running `sudo service postgresql restart`.

Where should I search in such a case? Is it a "common" problem? With no logs, I don't know what to do. How can I be relatively "sure" it will not randomly happen anymore?

*Side note: Here is the detail of the postgreSQL log after I restarted:*

```
2017-03-16 12:20:52 CET [857-2] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2017-03-16 12:20:52 CET [857-3] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2017-03-16 12:20:52 CET [6829-1] XXXXX@YYYY FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command at character 15
2017-03-16 12:20:52 CET [6829-2] XXXXX@YYYY STATEMENT:  select * from "users" where "users"."id" = $1 and "users"."deleted_at" is null limit 1
2017-03-16 12:20:52 CET [6644-1] XXXXX@YYYY FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command at character 15
2017-03-16 12:20:52 CET [6644-2] XXXXX@YYYY STATEMENT:  select * from "users" where "users"."id" = $1 and "users"."deleted_at" is null limit 1
2017-03-16 12:20:52 CET [6649-1] XXXXX@YYYY FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command at character 15
2017-03-16 12:20:52 CET [6649-2] XXXXX@YYYY STATEMENT:  select * from "users" where "users"."id" = $1 and "users"."deleted_at" is null limit 1
2017-03-16 12:20:52 CET [6580-1] XXXXX@YYYY FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command at character 15
2017-03-16 12:20:52 CET [6580-2] XXXXX@YYYY STATEMENT:  select * from "users" where "users"."id" = $1 and "users"."deleted_at" is null limit 1
2017-03-16 12:20:52 CET [6768-1] XXXXX@YYYY FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command at character 15
2017-03-16 12:20:52 CET [6768-2] XXXXX@YYYY STATEMENT:  select * from "users" where "email" = $1 and "users"."deleted_at" is null limit 1
2017-03-16 12:20:52 CET [6253-1] XXXXX@YYYY FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2017-03-16 12:20:52 CET [6253-2] XXXXX@YYYY STATEMENT:  alter table "users" add column "email_confirmed" boolean not null default '1'
2017-03-16 12:20:52 CET [8465-1] XXXXX@YYYY FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2017-03-16 12:20:52 CET [913-2] LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
2017-03-16 12:20:52 CET [6586-1] XXXXX@YYYY FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command at character 15
2017-03-16 12:20:52 CET [6586-2] XXXXX@YYYY STATEMENT:  select * from "users" where "users"."id" = $1 and "users"."deleted_at" is null limit 1
2017-03-16 12:20:52 CET [31969-1] XXXXX@YYYY FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2017-03-16 12:20:52 CET [6300-1] XXXXX@YYYY FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2017-03-16 12:20:52 CET [6974-1] XXXXX@YYYY FATAL:  the database system is shutting down
2017-03-16 12:20:52 CET [906-1] LOG:  shutting down
2017-03-16 12:20:52 CET [6980-1] XXXXX@YYYY FATAL:  the database system is shutting down
2017-03-16 12:20:52 CET [6978-1] XXXXX@YYYY FATAL:  the database system is shutting down
2017-03-16 12:20:52 CET [6975-1] XXXXX@YYYY FATAL:  the database system is shutting down
2017-03-16 12:20:52 CET [6977-1] XXXXX@YYYY FATAL:  the database system is shutting down
2017-03-16 12:20:52 CET [6976-1] XXXXX@YYYY FATAL:  the database system is shutting down
2017-03-16 12:20:52 CET [6983-1] XXXXX@YYYY FATAL:  the database system is shutting down
2017-03-16 12:20:52 CET [6979-1] XXXXX@YYYY FATAL:  the database system is shutting down
2017-03-16 12:20:52 CET [6982-1] XXXXX@YYYY FATAL:  the database system is shutting down
2017-03-16 12:20:52 CET [6981-1] XXXXX@YYYY FATAL:  the database system is shutting down
2017-03-16 12:20:52 CET [6985-1] XXXXX@YYYY FATAL:  the database system is shutting down
2017-03-16 12:20:52 CET [6984-1] XXXXX@YYYY FATAL:  the database system is shutting down
2017-03-16 12:20:52 CET [906-2] LOG:  database system is shut down
2017-03-16 12:20:53 CET [7002-1] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-03-16 12:20:52 CET
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the statement that caused your problem:

```
alter table "users" add column "email_confirmed" boolean not null default '1'
```

Such an `ALTER TABLE` requires an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock on the table, which conflicts even with read access.

Now the table `users` seems to be a busy table, which normally is no problem (unless two transactions try to write the same row) since the table locks they require don't conflict with each other.

Now along comes `ALTER TABLE` and has to wait until all earlier transactions on the table (which hold at least an `ACCESS SHARE` lock on the table) are done.
All queries to the table that start *after* the `ALTER TABLE` have to queue behind it, because the lock they need conflicts with the lock that the `ALTER TABLE` needs.

Once the `ALTER TABLE` gets its `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock it should be done rather quickly, and things go back to normal.

Now there is one riddle left: all the other interrupted queries in your log look like they are really short queries, so it is not obvious why you would have to wait that long – they should be done in a couple of microseconds.

To explain that, remember that a lock is not released when the query is finished, but is held until the end of the transaction. So if you run a short query in a transaction and then leave the transaction open, this idle database session will *also* block the `ALTER TABLE`. You might not notice under normal circumstances, particularly if all transactions are read-only, but in this case it will prove detrimental.

As an aside, there are other negative side effects of transactions that are kept open, notably that `VACUUM` cannot do its work, and your tables and indexes can get bloated.

You can check if your application has that problem by checking `state` from the `pg_stat_activity` system view. If you can regularly see sessions that are `idle in transaction` and stay that way for a while, you are looking at the root cause of your problem. This should be fixed!

Instead of restarting the server, you could also have interrupted the `ALTER TABLE` statement.

If you ever run into such a problem again, query the `pg_locks` system view. You will see that the session running the `ALTER TABLE` has a lock that has `granted = FALSE`, because it is waiting for a table lock. You can also see which other sessions are holding a lock on the table.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's clear and I think you are right! "Then it takes a while to process": it was really fast when running in local with the same database (only ~200 users in both production and local). And as far as I know, there are always only a few users connected on this application. Can I find what "ALTER TABLE" was waiting for? +1 for now, I will accept your answer asap.

Comment: Well, you can see all the queries that were active (running or waiting for a lock) at shutdown time in the log you quoted. Of course it can be that there was a long running transaction that did nothing, but kept a lock on the table that blocked the `ALTER TABLE` indefinitely. See if there are any sessions in status "idle in transaction". They may be the root cause of your problem.

Comment: Thanks again! Last precision and I let you go: "See if there are any sessions in status "idle in transaction"": I can't see it anymore since I restarted my postgreSQL service, right?

Comment: To clear up all your questions, I have extended the answer considerably. I also noticed a mistake I made: this `ALTER TABLE` does not have to rewrite the table and will never take long once it has got its lock. Ask away if anything is still unclear.